# Twilio can't continue to play audio if wrong key press/digit is received

Tags: java, twilio

I am new to Twilio. What I am actually trying to achieve is that:

When a user gets a call the audio continues to play custom message, until user presses the  expected key '1'.

If the user presses '1', I want Twilio to do what I specify in my action, which will work.

But if user presses any other key just don't do anything and continue to play the same custom message and do the specific action on time out, if user doesn't press '1'. Ex. `<Redirect>`

I read the Twilio documentation, but didn't find any information how to do this. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#hints

The documentation says **"After the first digit is received the audio will stop playing."** I want to avoid this.

Can someone guide me, If this is even possible using Twilio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually can't avoid this (as far as I know). The way TWIML works (Twilio's mark-up language) is that a digit is gathered and sent to the server for processing. In other words, the gather of the digit is completely separate from deciding what to do with that digit.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is true.

Edit: The best thing you can do is to probably have some audio say, "That's an invalid option" and then restart the original audio you were playing.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here, that's exactly correct on how things work. Good idea with the message and redirecting to the original action.

Comment: @shieldstory thank you for your feedback, I had thought about that earlier, to play an invalid audio and then restart the original action. But I want to avoid this as you have mentioned it doesn't seem to be possible as of now. I will see what are my other options.

Comment: @philnash Its great that Twilio devs are looking at issues here.

Comment: @Aniks We just want to make sure everyone is having a good experience with Twilio, feel free to ask more questions and we'll find them!

Comment: @philnash As mentioned in this thread, I have changed my implementation to send a new TwiML response same as it was generated previously. The message gets played from start again as I want. But I think in background the old message is also playing in parallel with it. And I can hear two voices. Can you guide me anything on this?

Comment: That sounds very weird! Do you have a recording of it? Might be best to get in touch with help@twilio.com.

Answer (score 1):

Shieldstroy is correct.

Here's how you'd handle this case:

```
//this code is in the original voice script
        twiml.Gather(
                    numDigits: 1,
                    input: new List<InputEnum>() { InputEnum.Dtmf },
                    timeout: 5,
                    method: "POST",
                    action: new System.Uri(Startup.hostAddress + "/TwilioCallbacks/InputResponse")
                    );
```

I'm working with C# here, but the Java implementation would be conceptually the same. The explanation below will explain what's happening exactly, and hopefully give you and idea how to proceed.

```
//C# Web Callback method structure
public ActionResult InputResponse(VoiceRequest request)
{
        int digit = 0;
        //create a new voice script
        var twiml = new VoiceResponse();
        try
        {
            //convert the digit to an int
            digit = Convert.ToInt32(request.Digits);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            //if the digit comes back as NaN for some reason, lets write an exception to debug 
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
        }

        //switch statement for which digit has been pressed
        switch (digit)
        {
            case 1:
                   twiml.Say("You have chosen the correct digit");
                   break;
            case 2: 
                   twiml.Say("You have chosen the other possible correct digit");
            default: 
                   twiml.Say("You have pressed an invalid digit")
                   //since an invalid digit has been pressed, we redirect to the 
                   //original voice script
                   var redirect( new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Redirect(
                                     new System.Uri.(originalVoiceScriptURL));
                   twiml.Append(redirect);
        }
    return TwiML(twiml);
}
```

So, if you can humor the inappropriate C#, the original script gathers the digits, and redirects the user to the InputResponse script. At this stage, you figure out what digits have been pressed, and direct the call script depending on the input.

It's impossible for the original script to know which key has been pressed, as the gather is happening inside the phone system. There's not an actual live connection between your software and the phone system, rather, you've directed the phone system ahead of time to gather digits. Once the phone system has gathered the digits, it knows to call your InputResponse method, and send to your server which digits have been keyed.

It's only at this stage that your software can possibly know which digit has been keyed.